# 2 Smaller Drives or 1 Large Partitioned for Separate OS

Tags: windows, macos, hard-drive, partitioning

I have found a few questions similar to this, but those are assumed with a single OS and this is a different question. What I am wanting to do is have Windows and OS X on my computer. This is a custom build computer so I could install two internal drives if that's best. I was originally thinking to just install two 500GB drives, one for each OS. But I was told that it might be best to partition one large drive (in this case 1TB). I wanted to know what is best over all. What would be easier to build (installing the OS and jamming in the case as this is my first computer)? What would be easier to boot with? Would the partitioned drive be slower? Or is the speed difference be insignificant?

Again, this is two *separate* OS. I am not trying to use two drives with one OS. Also I don't really care about trying to switch from one OS to another quickly (if I have to shut done one system to boot the other it's fine). The point of the two OS is that I like OS X for work and Windows for gaming. Another thing I should mention is that I was going to use something like Virtual Box to partition the OS if I went that option. Or would it be better to "physically" [partition](https://superuser.com/questions/399562/can-partitioning-a-hard-drive-specifically-via-boot-camp-slow-down-a-computer) (using the disk manager on an OS)?

Comment: There are no real differences, except for the obvious ones when you use two hard drives instead of one (if one HDD fails, you can still boot; things like that).  Also, you can put different partition table types on the two disks, if you want.  It's all up to your preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purely based on the assumption that they're identical drives in terms of performance/size and the cost of an extra drive isn't an issue: I think going with 2 drives is the better option. Though it's only a marginal benefit (esp. if you know what you're doing), It keeps things less complicated as far as initial setup.

The only real benefit that comes to mind by using one large drive is space flexibility (resizing partitions) if necessary. For example, if you decided down the road that Windows needs more space and OS X needs less, you could probably resize the partitions without having to create another one on a separate drive.

What I would do personally: Use a smaller, faster, more expensive solid state drive for the OS partitions, and then use a larger, slower, but cheaper mechanical HDD for data storage. I would partition/format the data drive as exFAT because both operating systems have native support for it, without the limitations of FAT32 (although OS X might be better at dealing with NTFS than it used to be).

That said, it's really up to you. I wouldn't worry about a performance hit solely because of the way the drives are partitioned.

Comment: Ok that is what I was thinking and cost is definitely not a problem (using a i7- 5820K). I did originally think about getting two very small (as small as possible really) SSDs for the OS and repartition the 1TB family external hard drive to have a section dedicated to just me (or just buy a new smaller one). I'll just have to see if having 3 internal drives is viable as far as space inside the case is concerned.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend 2 drives and using RAID 0 to make a single drive from them (assuming your hardware can support this).  This way your os will only see a single drive and you can partition it normally, but you can get higher speeds as both disks are used.

The downside is that if 1 of the disks fails, ALL of the data is LOST.